# Not able to drag and drop files between packages in VSCode

Tags: java, visual-studio-code

[image]

Hi, This is my file structure, I wanted to move UrlCheckController file to io.javabrains.isthesiteup package. But VSCode is not letting me drag and drop.

Comment: Have you tried using the `IS-THE-SITE-UP` tab instead of the `JAVA PROJECTS` tab?

Comment: @AndrewHulterstrom, Yes it works, what's the difference between both tabs? Why can't drag and dro in JAVA PROJECTS tab?

Comment: @AnjanaOuseph. `JAVA PROJECTS` is more focused on showing project structure. It's recommended that users operate on `Current Opened Project` itself.